# C - Is there a way to leave a variable unchanged outside of the loop?

Tags: c, cs50

I've tried searching for the answer to this question, which is a little tricky when you don't know exactly what you're searching for, but here goes.

I'm making my way through CS50 at the moment (very new at this - I know a bit of HTML/CSS and my day job is in marketing). I'm on the final problem of week 1 - I'm making it tricky for myself by doing the harder problems as well as the easy ones, but I'm keen to learn. So far we haven't talked about arrays, which I suspect might be the answer to this question, but without more knowledge I can't be sure.

I'm working on a credit card validator, where I have to do things like get the length of the card number to validate, add different digits etc. Where I'm struggling, is that if I alter a variable inside a loop in some way, when I go to use that variable again, it has the new value in it - not the original one.

How do I store the original value somewhere so it can be accessed without me having to create dozens of new variables to act as placeholders? (Note - the below is just a tiny snippet of my code as an example - I didn't want to include the whole thing)

e.g.

```
long long credit;           // credit card number
long long len;              // used to work out len of card number - feeds into count

// validate length of credit card number and get length of card

len = credit;
while (len > 0)
{
    len /= 10;
    count ++;
}
```

In the above example, if I want to use `len` again further down in my code, it's value will be 0. How do I ensure the original value stays somewhere for me to access in future loops?

I suspect I need to somehow use an array, but so far we've only covered off data types, Booleans, operators, conditional statements and loops (plus `printf`). All of the info I've found online about arrays talks about needing to specify the array size (the point is I don't know in this example - the values can vary between 13 and 16 digits) and seem more complex than this problem calls for.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something really simple - I just don't know what it is!

EDIT: Thanks everyone who contributed answers to my very first question! While there may be "better" solutions, it seems that given the constraints I have with my solution specification that I was doing ok and was just overthinking it really. I took the advice from people to copy variables and finally got everything working a few minutes ago.

If anybody would like to see it (although I'm sure my code could do with improvements), my solution is [here](https://gist.github.com/arianned/693451eca33118017299b7144e1c90ab).

The original specification that I had to meet, was [here](http://docs.cs50.net/problems/credit/credit.html).

Once again, really appreciated the feedback - I appreciate that this isn't a tutorial site - but sometimes it can be hard to work out what you don't know. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Take a copy into another variable and use this in your loop?

Comment: Not clear what your problem is. If you don't want the cake to be eate, just don't eat it! Explicitly: If you don't want the variable to change, do not change it!.

Comment: Use the `count`...that means something, is not it?

Comment: Thanks @FelixPalmen - that's what I've been doing so far - I've got an insane number of variables which are copies of different things. I just wasn't sure if there was an easier/cleaner way? It seems... wasteful?

Comment: Since `len` is already a copy of `credit`, you just do `len = credit` again if you need to use it in a similar way.

Comment: Hi @SouravGhosh - I use the `count` further down for other things - in a `for` loop, where it then also ends up being zero. This is just one example of several in the code - it's only a small snippet.

Comment: @Arianne if in your *real* code, the number of variables gets *insane* that's a sign it's time for refactoring. Divide your code into functions *doing one thing*.

Comment: @Olaf I'm not sure it's that easy? :) I have to change the variables to find things like the penultimate digit, the first 2 digits, to add and multiply things... short of doing what Felix suggested and creating copies of all the variables, I'm not sure if there's a leaner way to do it?

Comment: @JJJ - I didn't realise that could work - I could just copy it again within a new loop?

Comment: @FelixPalmen I'm endeavouring to do that a little - separating out each bit cleanly. I think there's probably more to do and I may be better off starting again and trying to iterate more clearly.

Comment: Unless you're doing mathematics on the credit card number, representing it as a `long long` in the first place is a poor idea.  It's really just a string of characters.  Your project will go easier if you treat it as a string.

Comment: @JLH that's interesting - we've been told specifically to use `long long` to get the number. I get the penultimate digits, I've been using division and modulo, which is what we've been taught so far.

Comment: BTW i doubt it's a good idea to store a credit card number in a long, but yes if this is just an exercise to work with numbers it is fine Iguess.

Comment: @Arianne Whoever suggested you use a long long is either not a good programmer, or is testing your ability to get that number in a representation that is convenient to work with.

Comment: @JLH it's the team at Harvard - as this problem is one of their challenges. They're very specific about the use of `long long` in the [specification](http://docs.cs50.net/problems/credit/credit.html)

Comment: Either use another variable or start using functions buddy.

Comment: Thanks @Shark - looks like I was on the right track with using more variables. Hopefully we'll get to functions :)

Comment: @Arianne: Without a [mcve] and the necessary information? I'm no clairvoyant. And this is not a tutoring site either. A good C book is strongly advised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for the declaration of additional blocks as in

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  int i=1;
  printf("before %d\n",i);
  {
    int i=0;
    printf("within %d\n",i);
  }
  printf("after %d\n",i);
  return(0);
}
```

which when executed yields

```
before 1
within 0
after 1
```

From the comment I grasp that a function invocation may be preferable which may be like

```
#include<stdio.h>
int div_10_count(long long val) {
    int count=0;
    while(val>0) {
        val /= 10;
        count++;
    }
    return(count);
}

int main() {
  long long val=10000000000L;
  printf("Before: val=%lld\n",val);
  printf("Returned: %d\n",div_10_count(val));
  printf("After: val=%lld\n",val);
  return(0);
}
```

shows

```
Before: val=10000000000
Returned: 11
After: val=10000000000
```

so the variable val remains unchanged even though the function works with it. This would be different when passing the parameter by reference, i.e. as indicated with the "&".

Comment: That makes sense - so chances are, depending on when I declare these variables, that's why I'm having a problem? I suspect Felix is right and I need to refactor.

Comment: In this case the val argument is a copy of the variable. It is a bit ugly to modify arguments, but if the function  is short like in this example it is I guess acceptable. The key take away is the function isolates the code so you don't have to worry about its variables and the function name clearly(?) communicates the function so you later have not to care how it does it. I would name it count_digits() instead as base 10 looks natural here.

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with using a temporary variable?

You can just make two variables

```
long long len;
long long lenWork;

len = yourValue;
lenWork = len;

/* Work with lenWork */
lenWork = len;
/* Once again */
lenWork = len;
/* etc... */
```

Comment: That's mostly what I've been doing so far - creating a variable that lives within each loop. I wasn't sure if there was an easier or cleaner way.

Comment: `for` loops work that way, and they are used everywhere

Comment: No, all solutions would create a copy, it is just a question how you present it in code. If you put your loop in its own method you would get the length parameter as a copy on the stack (and don't need to have a explicit variable. However it is also bad style to modify an argument.

Comment: @eckes This is where I find things really interesting - I don't know enough yet to know whether or not I'm doing things that could be considered "bad" in style. I guess that come with time!

Comment: Yes it's a matter of experience. However questioning yourself is a good start. You just sometimes need to make sure you don't overthink things.

Comment: @eckes I'm really good at overthinking things - always been an issue. It looks like there probably isn't a more straightforward way than what I've been doing (based on what we've been taught so far). Although I'll go through and refactor it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten to initialize the `count` variable to `0`.

Use more explicit variable names:

```
unsigned long long credit;  // credit card number

// get length of the credit card number
int count = 0;
for (unsigned long long tmp = credit; tmp > 0; tmp /= 10) {
    count++;
}
```

Here is a more direct method:

```
if (snprintf(NULL, 0, "%llu", credit) == 16) {
    /* credit card number has 16 digits */
}
```

You could also use a much simpler but less readable method:

```
if (credit >= 1000000000000000 && credit < 10000000000000000) {
    /* credit has 16 digits */
}
```

Comment: Thanks @chqrlie - I have initialised and set it to  `0` further up with my other variables - I should have included that one with my initial snippet of code. I've not used `snprintf` yet, but I've seen that mentioned in several solutions to similar projects.